# Trigger mysql para insertar datos de una tabla a otra

Tags: mysql, trigger

Tengo un problema al hacer el trigger. El trigger se ejecuta cada vez que inserto un usuario y este debería guardar en otra tabla un 0 como permiso de usuario y su corre electronico. Lo que pasa que no entiendo del todo como hacer para que recoja el email de la tabla. Tengo hecho esto:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertarTipoUsuario
AFTER INSERT ON usuarios
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO tipo_user(tipo_user, email_user)
   VALUES (0, `email`);
END;
```

Y claro algo estoy haciendo mal por que me da error en la línea del value, pero no entiendo el que ni como hacerlo correctamente.

Comment: ¿Qué error obtiene ?

Comment: El error es MySQL ha dicho: #1303 - Can't create a TRIGGER from within another stored routine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para acceder al nuevo valor insertado de su tabla usuarios, puede hacerlo con  `NEW.campotabla`, *(campotabla representa el nombre de la columna)* este tendrá el nuevo valor insertado de esa columna.

Su trigger quedaría de la siguiente forma, *(Cada vez que se realice un insert en su tabla usuarios, se realizará el insert en su tabla tipouser con el email correspondiente)*

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertarTipoUsuario
AFTER INSERT ON usuarios
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO tipo_user(tipo_user, email_user)
   VALUES (0, NEW.email);
END;
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero sigue sin funcionarme, el error que lanza es el siguiente: MySQL ha dicho: #1303 - Can't create a TRIGGER from within another stored routine

Comment: Vale, ya lo he solucionado, resulta que estaba volviendo loco al mysql repitiendo datos, ya que rellenaba los datos del formulario para crear el trigger y abajo en el código añadia todo el código, eliminando la parte del create hasta el begin ha funcionado. Gracias por la ayuda de antes.